# Sequences convergent to 'cycles'

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, definition

Consider sequences $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty\subset\mathbb R$. Is there a name for the following property?

> There exists $L\in\mathbb N$ such that:
>
> $$\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow\infty}x_{(kL+m)}=x^\ast_m$$
>
> for $m\in\{0,1,2,\dots,(L-1)\}$.

Here the $x^\ast_m$'s are not necessarily equal.

As an example, the sequence $x_n=(-1)^n +\frac n{n+1}$ has $x_{2n}\rightarrow 2$ and $x_{2n+1}\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. In this case $L=2$ (choosing $L$ to be minimal).

Comment: Basically, you have $L$ sequences "interweaved". I doubt there is any special name for them, but perhaps some analyst will know better than I.

Comment: If I had naming rights, I would call it an $L$-colored sequence.

Comment: I'd call it a limit-periodic sequence, but I'm not aware that a standard term exists for that.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. @alex.jordan, some research following your comment has lead me to believe that such sequences are called "asymptotically periodic". I will post an answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A sequence with the described property is called an *asymptotically periodic sequence*.

> A sequence is asymptotically periodic if its terms approach those of a periodic sequence. That is, the sequence $x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots$ is asymptotically periodic if there exists a periodic sequence $a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots$ for which:
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n - a_n = 0$$

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_sequence#Generalizations

Comment: +1 for the wikipedia reference. But, in analogy to this terminology, one might call a convergent sequence *asymptotically constant*, which I do not like very much. :-)